# Testing the effect of a customer loyalty initiative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, marketing

I work for a company with a chain of auto workshops. We are interested in testing the effect of a data gathering initiative on customer loyalty (visits per year) and spend per visit, hoping that the extra data will enable us to offer better service. The plan is basically to ask all customers for permission to gather the data, and test whether this improves average loyalty and/or spend, including both those that accept the offer and those that decline. We have plenty of historical data to establish the loyalty and spend baseline for a control group (using the ones that decline as comparison seems to make a selection bias). Right now I'm trying to establish how large a sample (a few thousand should be very feasible), and how long time I need to run the test to establish that there is a statistically significant effect. I have data from the third party offering the data gathering as a service that would give us an idea of the expected effect.

Zooming in on the individual customer, it would seem that he/she has a somewhat random number of events warranting a workshop visit each year. The parameter we want to measure is, in a sense, the probability that the customer chooses to visit our workshop vs. visiting a competitor. Our hypothesis is that those that accept our offer are more likely (have a higher probability) of choosing us. In that sense, the individual customer would seem to follow a binomial distribution, but with an unknown size n (number of events).

For the group of N customers as a whole, it would then seem that the total number of workshop visits would be the sum of N binomial distributions with different sizes n and probability p. I guess the distribution of the n would be a Poisson distribution(?), but the p's could vary wildly depending on customer preference, acceptance, etc.

It would seem that there are [no simple ways to treat the sum of binomial distributions](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA266969.pdf), so I feel that I'm hitting a wall.

My questions are:

1. Am I making this too complicated? Could I, for example, assume that the number of workshop visits for each customer follows a Poisson distribution (the example [here](https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/statistics/hypothesis-testing/hypothesis-testing-with-the-poisson-distribution.html) seems quite close to my case)?
2. Can someone point me in the right direction with regards to calculating the expected time needed to run the test, given the sample size and expected improvement in loyalty?

I realize that these questions probably will make me be considered a "newbie" in here. For this, I hope for your patience - my college statistics course was 25 years ago :-)